# Ctrl+click combination doesn't work with the Ask Ubuntu search results in QupZilla

Tags: discussion

Why the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> combination doesn't work over the search results of posts or Q&A links in AskUbuntu? It works for the highlighted links on the right side panel but not for the search results, when applying <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> , it takes me directly to that Q&A instead of opening the specific Q&A in a separate tab in the browser.

I noticed that it's browser specific; it happens in QupZilla browser.

Comment: Questions on the site itself should be asked in [meta]. Anyway, might be something wrong with your browser. Ctrl+Click works fine for me in search results.

Comment: @muru My bad, I'll keep that in mind next time :)